# remove/uninstall forever firefox developer tools

Tags: firefox, web-development, firefox-developer-tools

After latest update to firefox 28 i cannot disable this developer tools. I want to disable it because it overrode firebug hotkey (ctrl+shift+c).

I have tried about:config and switch to false everything with `devtools.*.enabled`

restarted firefox - no effect. How to turn this developer tools off or even uninstall it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of Firebug are you using? I don't know how to disable the firefox stuff but [this issue](https://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=6991#c14) seems to has been fixed in recent versions.

Comment: Firebug version is 1.11.4. Now i have installed 1.12.7 and seems like it's fixed! Thanks!